# get_terms (or tax_query) for term of current post?

Tags: functions, query, single

I've seen many solutions but none seem to work for me... I've got a grid off the loop/content on `single.php` that renders the whole grid as is, so I use the function as below which works fine, but only if I specify the exact taxonomy term (`client-1`).

```
function my_query_args($query_args, $grid_name) {
if ($grid_name == 'client-grid') {
    $query_args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'client-1',
        ),
    );
}
return $query_args;
}
add_filter('tg_wp_query_args', 'my_query_args');
```

But I want the term of the **current post** instead so I thought that below would work, but it renders all posts in the grid no matter what I do.

```
function my_query_args($terms_list, $grid_name) {
if ($grid_name == 'client-grid') {

    $terms_list = get_terms
        (array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'parent' => 0,
        )
    );  
}
return $terms_list;

}
add_filter('tg_wp_query_args', 'my_query_args');
```

Thankful for any input.

**EDIT**

Thinking of something like this (which obvs doesn't works), but anyone that can point in the right direction?

```
$term_id = get_queried_object_id();

function my_query_args($query_args, $grid_name) {
if ($grid_name == 'JTS-SINGLE') {

    $query_args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $term_id
        ),
    );
}
return $query_args;

}
add_filter('tg_wp_query_args', 'my_query_args', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

This was what I was looking for and it works like a charm.

```
function my_query_args($query_args, $grid_name) {

$term_list = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category' )[0]->slug;

if ($grid_name == 'JTS-SINGLE') {
    $query_args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( $term_list ),
        ),
    );
}
return $query_args;

}
add_filter('tg_wp_query_args', 'my_query_args', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [wp_get_post_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) which allows you to specify a posiID, which is what I think you are getting at

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that as well (wp_get_post_terms i/o get_terms) but I get all posts as output there as well - for some reason it returns all categories i/o just the current posts term. I might miss something very obvs cause getting a bit of WP fatigue from this...

Comment: Can we have the template file code your loop is in? What is 'tg_wp_query_args' - is this related to https://theme.co/apex/forums/topic/offsetting-posts-with-the-grid-plugin/

Comment: The grid is outside the loop and is called via 

    <?php echo The_Grid('JTS-SINGLE'); ?>

The query works fine with hardcoded terms, forexample 'terms'    => 2, but I want the term to be dynamically return.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be in the same ballpark [https://theme.co/apex/forums/topic/offsetting-posts-with-the-grid-plugin/](https://theme.co/apex/forums/topic/offsetting-posts-with-the-grid-plugin/) but doesn't really help me. It's the same grid plugin.

Comment: Problem solved.